# couldn't find with id= when passing parameter in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm very new to rails and this is my first application. I'm trying to display all the questions that belong to a batch_set. batch_set has many questions and question belongs to a batch_set. Also, batch has many batch_sets and batch_set belongs to a batch.

In the batch show page, I've linked a new page called batch_questions (which will contain all the questions related to that batch) and passed the batch id to it.

```
<%= link_to b.title, batches_batch_questions_path(:batches => @batch.id) %>
```

My url for the batch_questions page looks like this

http://localhost:3000/batches/batch_questions?batches=1

So, in the batch_question action which is in the batch controller, I'm trying to get the batch id. How do I do that? I tried this.

```
@batch = Batch.find(params[:batch])
```

I'm getting an error saying

> "Couldn't find Batch with 'id'= "

So how do I assign @batch the parameter that is passed in the URL?

Comment: You send param `batches`, but look for `batch`

Comment: I feel very dumb for making such a silly mistake. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code in your controller:

```
@batch = Batch.find(params[:batches])
```

Comment: I made such a silly mistake. Thanks a lot for answering!